# Which is better: "Supervisory Experience"; "Supervisor Experience"; or "Experience as a Supervisor"?

Tags: phrase-request, phrase-choice

I'm looking for the appropriate heading in a CV to express experience of supervising students' degree projects. Which would you say would be the better choice for this – "Supervisory Experience"; "Supervisor Experience"; or "Experience as a Supervisor" (or something else entirely)? I have found some support for all three phrases, but I haven't been able to determine which would actually be the better choice. So... as usual, I'm forever grateful for any input here.

Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't "experience of supervising students' degree projects" say it more clearly? But if the section of the CV is about your work experience, then do you really need to repeat "experience"? You could just say "Supervising students" and then go into detail.

Comment: Well, "supervisory experience" isn't necessarily the same thing as "supervisor experience" since "supervisor experience" denotes experience as a "supervisor," while "supervisory experience" denotes experience in which one supervised, even if not a "supervisor" in any official or designated capacity.

Comment: Perhaps you should switch from ***supervising*** to ***mentoring***, to avoid confusion with "managing / supervising" ***junior staff***, which is a much more likely meaning in the context of most CVs.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you for your comment! I see what you mean, but the thing is, I'm translating a template for a CV, where the headings are already determined in the original, so I need to stick to those...

Comment: So what is the heading? Is that part of the template, or the experience you need to translate?

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Excellent point! So, would you say "Supervisor Experience" would be the best choice then?

Comment: @WeatherVane Do you know Swedish? :) The literal translation from the original would be "Supervisor Experience"

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, the heading is part of the template, and it's the template I'm translating.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Good point; in the context I don't think it'll be an issue though. But thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in the UK the person who supervises a student project is know as a supervisor. The least ambiguous of the three you quote seems to me to be "Experience as a supervisor". The phrase "Supervisor experience" is slightly vague, it might be read as experience of supervisors by a hasty reader. "Supervisory experience" does not seem to me to be what an academic would say although it is clearly not wrong and I find it hard to enunciate why it comes over as unnatural.

The suggestion of mentor put forward in a comment does not seems right to me. A mentor is a more general role, we can all have mentors but only people in some junior role can be supervised.

Comment: Thank you so much, mdewey! It's exactly this not-always-so-easy-to-explain native speaker intuition I'm after! I'll go with "Experience as a supervisor" then :)